# How to change property names when serializing with dart json_serializable?

Tags: json, dart, json-serialization

Here is a json file person.json

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

Here is the Person class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  /// The generated code assumes these values exist in JSON.
  final String first_name, last_name;

  /// The generated code below handles if the corresponding JSON value doesn't
  /// exist or is empty.
  final DateTime? dateOfBirth;

  Person({required this.first_name, required this.last_name, this.dateOfBirth});

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$PersonToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

Here is how to convert json into the person object.

```
Person.fromJson(personJson);
```

The json is using the snake case with underscore, how can I change the snake_case to camelCase when serializing the json? How to change **first_name** to **firstName** and **last_name** to **lastName**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `json_serializable`'s `README.md`:

> To generate to/from JSON code for a class, annotate it with `JsonSerializable`. You can provide arguments to `JsonSerializable` to configure the generated code. You can also customize individual fields by annotating them with [`JsonKey`](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey-class.html) and providing custom arguments.

You should be able to do:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  @JsonKey(name: 'first_name')
  final String firstName;

  @JsonKey(name: 'last_name')
  final String lastName;

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@JsonSerializable()  
class Person 
{   
final String firstName;
final String lastName;  
}
```

Instead of defining @JsonKey(name: ) for each field, you can just use field_rename: snake in build.yaml configuration file. It will generate all fields json keys to snake case. Check json serializable build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `nauman mir`'s answer I was able to add a `build.yaml` file to my app package which had all the API Client logic and then I specified this as my build.yaml in that module.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          explicit_to_json: true
          field_rename: snake
```

This was then generated after running `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` in that module.

[image: Generated JSON Serialisable code]